# How do I get a specific user outputting their name once they logged in

Tags: php, html, pdo

Ok, I will elaborate but keep it simple.
1. Once User Registers, their information is stored into a database (already Completed)
2. Once User goes to login and successfully gets authorization to visit homepage. How do I output their first and last name.

I know this is php, but I am using PDO and php. Hopefully my code can help you help me. Thanks

```
//INSERT THE INFORMATION INTO THE DATABASE
      $query = "INSERT INTO stable (email, first_name, last_name, user_name, user_pass, re_password ) VALUES (:useremail, :firstname, :lastname, :username, :password, :repassword)"; 
      $result = $linkID->prepare($query);
      $result->execute(array(
          ':useremail' => $useremail,
          ':firstname' => $firstname,
          ':lastname' => $lastname,
          ':username' => $username,
          ':password' => $password,
          ':repassword' => $repassword
          ));

      //Displays an appropriate message
      if ($result) {
        // logged in
        header('Location: ../inc/home.php');
      };
```

Html:

```
<div id="div2" class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron text-center" style=" background-color:transparent ; position:relative; bottom:145px;">
        <p><?php <!--Can you please help me output name here--> ?></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How are you authorizing the users? You're not authorizing a user in the shown code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provided you are authorizing the user and session ID, and storing your variables correctly you can display their name with

```
<?php echo "Hello $firstname $lastname!";
```

**edit** 
You may want to wrap the above code in its own variable, that way you can do:

```
 if ($result) {
    // logged in
    header('Location: ../inc/home.php');
    $variablename = "Hello $firstname $lastname!"
  };

<div id="div2" class="container">
<div class="jumbotron text-center" style=" background-color:transparent ; position:relative; bottom:145px;">
    <p><?php echo "$variablename" ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please upvote and/or mark as answer if this helped you, that way others can use your question as reference in the future. :D @GianniZamora